# Override the dependency version used at runtime from command-line

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, checkstyle

**General**: I need execute maven plugin from command line with overridden dependency version (plugin dependency). Plugin will not be defined in project pom.

**Concrete**: I need to execute [`maven-checkstyle-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html) as step in teamcity build; this plugin will not be defined project pom. I use following command-line:

```
 mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check -Dencoding=UTF-8
```

But I need to execute plugin with latest [checkstyle](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.puppycrawl.tools%22%20AND%20a%3A%22checkstyle%22) as showed [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html).

POM xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</plugin>
```

command-line:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check
```

POM xml:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
          <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

command-line:

```
?
```

Comment: Why not defining in pom ? Does not make sense...Overridding dependency version is not possible on command line. Why do you need this?

Comment: You most probably cannot do this. A possible trick would be to execute a pre-build step where you make a copy of the target `pom.xml` file, enhance it adding this plugin configuration into its `pluginManagement` section, then execute the build on this alternative pom file via the `-f` option (e.g. `mvn -f enhanced-pom.xml clean install`). A better solution would be to have an enterprise maven parent pom where to place CI related checks/requirements, used across all maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to create a [Maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) with your settings, then activate this profile when building on CI.

Example profile:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>ci</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Example how to enable it on TeamCity: `mvn checkstyle:check -Pci`

Usually `execution` section is added to profile configuration to make the plugin goal run automatically as part of normal build at a certain phase, but only when `ci` profile is enabled via, e.g., `mvn install -Pci`.