# Java override dependency with command line

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am building a jarfile with maven.

My question is: how to override a dependency with command line during jar execution?

Here is my command line

```
java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\param" -jar Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you could try with the answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219771/override-the-dependency-version-used-at-runtime-from-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You can't. When using the `-jar` option, the class path is controlled by the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest, and you cannot change it. The only ways to change it while still using `-jar` is by either modifying the manifest, or replacing the jar file referenced by the manfifest.

Another alternative is to not use `-jar`, but instead use `-cp` to specify the class path (you will need to specify all dependencies yourself!), and explicitly specify the main class.